# Can I get a list of more than fifteen of the most recent notebooks opened?

Tags: notebooks, files-and-directories

When I go to the pull-down options for “File”, one of them is “Open Recent”. It lists
the last 15 notebooks opened.

Is their any procedure to follow to get more (than 15) of the latest opened notebooks?

That is, something akin to “Show History” in a browser (like Safari).

Comment: The front end option `"NotebooksMenuHistoryLength"` controls the length of your history; in your case, it seems to be set to 15, so the other older notebooks you opened have already been forgotten. You could do something like `SetOptions[$FrontEnd, "NotebooksMenuHistoryLength" -> 20]` if you need a longer history record.

Comment: `Mathematica | Preferences ... | Advanced | Open Option Inspector | Global Options | Menu Settings | NotebooksMenuHistoryLength` or at `Open Option Inspector` search for `history`

Answer (score 10):

As commented by [J. M.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/50/j-m) you can persistently increase the menu size with:

```
SetOptions[$FrontEnd, "NotebooksMenuHistoryLength" -> 20]   (* 20 is arbitrary *)
```

You can extract a list of Notebook locations with:

```
NotebooksMenu /. Options[$FrontEnd] // MapAt[ToFileName @@ #[[1, ;; 2]] &, {All, 2}]
```

Comment: Tried the suggested SetOptions[$FrontEnd, "NotebooksMenuHistoryLength" -> 20], but didn't seem to "take". Something more to do than just simply issuing this command?

Comment: @Paul Did you restart the Front End?  If so and it still didn't work I'll need to look at this again.  Which OS and *Mathematica* revision are you using?

Comment: No, sorry, didn't restart FrontEnd. May I naively ask what would be involved--quitting kernel,...? I'm using "10.2.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (July 7, 2015)"

Comment: @Paul I just mean fully closing and reopening *Mathematica,* nothing unusual.  If that did/does not work there may be a hard upper limit to the history length, as I don't believe I have ever kept one that long.

Comment: OK, thanks very much  for the feedback! So, could the situation be this? J. M. noted "..., it seems to be set to 15, so the other older notebooks you opened have already been forgotten. " So, maybe even if the option does get appropriately reset, the number shown will simply start off at 15 and then keep growing to the new limit as different notebooks are opened?

Comment: @Paul Well yes, I agree with what he wrote, and since it was already written I did not repeat it.  I assumed you opened additional Notebooks after increasing the history length to check if it worked.